# Linq to entities: cast result to multiple listed complex types

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to create a single linq query which populates the following models in the `CompanyViewModel` constructor:

```
public class CompanyViewModel
{
    public IList<CompanyUserViewModel> CompanyUsers { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class CompanyUserViewModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public IList<UserOperationViewModel> UsersOperations { get; set; }
}

public class UserOperationViewModel
{
    public Operation Operation { get; set; }
    public int Permission { get; set; }
}
```

Currently I've got the following query:

```
return db.Users.Where(u => u.CompanyId == companyId)
               .Select(u => new CompanyUserViewModel { 
                    User = u,
                    UsersOperations = db.UsersInOperations
                        .Where(uo => uo.UserId == uo.UserId)
                        .Select(uo => new UserOperationViewModel{
                             Operation = uo.Operation,
                             Permission = uo.Permission
                        }).ToList()
                }).ToList();
```

Which builds, but when the page runs I get

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WoodCo.Models.BusinessObject.UserOperationViewModel] ToList[UserOperationViewModel](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WoodCo.Models.BusinessObject.UserOperationViewModel])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

What does one do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your view model properties to use `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IList<T` and remove the `.ToList()` calls.

Comment: I've thought of the possibility, it's just on my views (I'm using ASP.NET MVC 2) I'm accessing the item by an index ie. Model.CompanyUsers[x].UsersOperations[y].Permission in order for the default model binding to work.

Comment: You can split the query in two, then. First project onto an anonymous type, then `.AsEnumerable()`, then to list.